# How can I customize socket io reconnect url? Want to add one more request parameter on reconnect url

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to add one more request parameter on reconnect url.

Simple connection url:

```
http://192.168.0.91:8155/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426834118026-12&sid=6STHOzvQ1APcl0igAAAA
```

Reconnect url should be:

```
http://192.168.0.91:8155/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426834118026-12&sid=6STHOzvQ1APcl0igAAAA&token=xyz
```

Comment: And your question is? Your problem with doing that is? You have attempted it how?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solve it by changing the uri in the socket Manager.  I don't know if that is the right approach.

```
// Connect to your socket
var socket = io("your_url_here");

// And change the uri after that so it can be different in a reconnect attempt
socket.io.uri = "your_new_url_here";
```

Comment: this is not working for me. Are you shure its called uri?

Comment: This was working in 2015. I'm not sure if this is still working today.